# How to configure AWS CDK Bootstrap to use existing S3 buckets, IAM roles, and ECR repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Because of company policies, I am specified to create resources separately. Am I able to bootstrap with existing s3 buckets, IAM roles and ECR repository instead of having bootstrap create new ones?

I've looked at the default bootstrap template but it seems that its only for changing default names for resources.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you will need to create your custom [Stack Synthesizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.DefaultStackSynthesizer.html) and pass that to every stack in your app.

```
const mySynthesizer = new DefaultStackSynthesizer({
  fileAssetsBucketName: 'my-bucket',
  ...
});

new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', {
  synthesizer: mySynthesizer,
});
```